# Unable to update Amasty's extensions due to 'require magento/module-payment-services-saas-export 1.4.*' Error

Tags: extensions, amasty

```
Magento 2.4-p1
Smartwave Porto
13 Amasty extensions
```

I am having terrible problems with extensions from Amasty. Now I need to untick/uncheck the 'Billing address is same as Shipping address' and I can't do that due to Amasty's extensions changed the check-out (namely the One-Step-checkout extension which we have disabled but is still installed). Amasty claims there is an option to untick this in the latest version of their One-Step checkout but I am unable to update any of their extensions due to the following Error:

I run:

**composer update***

And this is the Error:

Problem 1

```
  - magento/payment-services[1.4.0, ..., 1.4.1] require magento/module-payment-services-saas-export 1.4.* -> satisfiable by magento/module-payment-services-saas-export[1.4.0, 1.4.1].

    - magento/payment-services[1.3.0, ..., 1.3.1] require magento/module-payment-services-saas-export 1.3.* -> satisfiable by magento/module-payment-services-saas-export[1.3.0, 1.3.1].

    - magento/payment-services[1.5.0, ..., 1.5.1] require magento/module-payment-services-saas-export 1.5.* -> satisfiable by magento/module-payment-services-saas-export[1.5.0, 1.5.1].

    - magento/module-payment-services-saas-export[1.4.0, ..., 1.4.1] require magento/services-connector ^1.2.2 -> satisfiable by magento/services-connector[1.2.3, 1.2.4].

    - magento/module-payment-services-saas-export[1.3.0, ..., 1.3.1] require magento/services-connector ^1.2.1 -> satisfiable by magento/services-connector[1.2.1, 1.2.3, 1.2.4].

    - magento/module-payment-services-saas-export[1.5.0, ..., 1.5.1] require magento/services-connector ^1.2.3 -> satisfiable by magento/services-connector[1.2.3, 1.2.4].

    - magento/services-connector[1.2.1, ..., 1.2.4] require firebase/php-jwt ^6.0.0 -> found firebase/php-jwt[v6.0.0, ..., v6.3.1] but the package is fixed to v5.5.1 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.

    - Root composer.json requires magento/payment-services ^1.3 -> satisfiable by magento/payment-services[1.3.0, ..., 1.5.1].

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
```

I've raised this to Amasty and they came back to me with the following:

*I've reviewed it with our specialists, and they confirmed that the difficulty seems to be related to the default Magento, I'm afraid. Unfortunately, it seems that some default extensions were not updated properly when updating Magento itself.
Please let me point out that the functionality of our extension strongly depends on the proper performance of the default Magento features. As the issue occurs on the side of the default Magento, its behavior should be fixed first. I’m afraid, according to our Policy, the Support Team developers are not allowed to troubleshoot the difficulties that are not related to Amasty extensions. So please, contact Magento support team and ask them to fix the issue for you.*

**How do I resolve the Errors** and is it true this is a Magento issue and has nothing to do with Amasty? **I've installed Magento 2.4.2-p1 and never update it in any way!**

---

This is an **EMERGENCY** - someone please help! I did what Tu Van suggested below and it brought my whole website down!

I ran the following command via Putty (SSH):

**composer update**

**And it now shows this Error on the front end (website):**

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory.
The following modules are outdated:
Amasty_CheckoutCore schema: current version - 1.0.0, required version - 1.1.0
Amasty_CheckoutCore data: current version - 1.0.0, required version - 1.1.0
Magecomp_Smspro schema: current version - 1.0.7, required version - 1.0.9
Magecomp_Smspro data: current version - 1.0.7, required version - 1.0.9

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory.
The following modules are outdated:
Amasty_CheckoutCore schema: current version - 1.0.0, required version - 1.1.0
Amasty_CheckoutCore data: current version - 1.0.0, required version - 1.1.0
Magecomp_Smspro schema: current version - 1.0.7, required version - 1.0.9
Magecomp_Smspro data: current version - 1.0.7, required version - 1.0.9
<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/amasty/aminvisiblecaptcha/Plugin/Framework/App/FrontControllerInterface/ValidateCaptcha.php:123]
#2 Amasty\InvisibleCaptcha\Plugin\Framework\App\FrontControllerInterface\ValidateCaptcha->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:151]
#3 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php:71]
#4 Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:151]
#5 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:169]
#6 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:23]
#7 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:116]
#8 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:23]
#9 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:263]
#10 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [pub/index.php:29]
</pre>
```

---

**UPDATED:
The issue has been resolved by removing broken magento/payment-services**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run `composer update`.

It will update `firebase/php-jwt` package and might be resolve your issue.

Comment: Please please please help me! I did it and it brought the whole website down! I don't know what to do! I will post the Error up above in my original post... PLEASE please please help me...

Comment: Just want to confirm, the issue was resolved by removing the broken module which is unneeded.

Comment: Our websites are all down. Would you please take a look at and tell me what you think? Thank you so much. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/363575/which-log-file-to-check-to-find-out-why-check-out-is-not-loading-on-mobile-phone