# Which log file to check to find out why Check-out is not loading on mobile phones and desktop?

Tags: mobile

```
Magento 2.4.2-p1
Smartwave Porto theme
13 extensions from Amasty
```

We have the Amasty's One Step Checkout but we don't use it (it's disabled but the Amasty One Step Checkout base is still installed). Everything used to work for customers ordering on mobile devices but now, when you click on 'Go To Checkout' on a smart phone (or a desktop), it loads:

Estimated Total
$12.34

up top and then *just shows the spinning wheel which never goes away...*

**Is there a log file (or anything else) I could check in order to try to figure out what might be causing this?**

---

UPDATED:

I have the following in debug.log:

```
[2023-01-11 21:10:49] main.WARNING: Broken reference: The element with the "sidebar.additional" ID wasn't found. Verify the ID and try again. [] []
[2023-01-11 21:10:53] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-01-11 21:10:53] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-01-11 21:10:53] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-01-11 21:10:53] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sw.sidenav' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.main', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-01-11 21:10:53] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sidebar_second_block' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.second', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-01-11 21:10:53] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'product_view_custom_block' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-01-11 21:10:53] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'currency' tries to reorder itself towards 'store_language', but their parents are different: 'header.panel' and 'porto_header' respectively. [] []
[2023-01-11 21:10:53] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.link' tries to reorder itself towards 'top.links', but their parents are different: 'header.links' and 'header.panel' respectively. [] []
[2023-01-11 21:10:53] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'yotpo_bottomline' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.addto', but their parents are different: 'product.info.main' and 'product.info.social' respectively. [] []
[2023-01-11 21:10:53] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sw.sidenav' tries to reorder itself towards 'category_leftnav', but their parents are different: 'sidebar.main' and '' respectively. [] []
[2023-01-11 21:10:53] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sidebar_second_block' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'sidebar.second' and '' respectively. [] []
[2023-01-11 21:10:53] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'skip_gallery_before' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.media.image', but their parents are different: 'skip_gallery_before.wrapper' and 'product.info.media' respectively. [] []
[2023-01-11 21:10:53] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'skip_gallery_after' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.media.image', but their parents are different: 'skip_gallery_after.wrapper' and 'product.info.media' respectively. [] []
[2023-01-11 21:10:53] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'amasty.rewards.highlight.container' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.form.content', but their parents are different: 'alert.urls' and 'product.info' respectively. [] []
[2023-01-11 21:10:53] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'product_view_custom_block' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'sidebar.additional' and '' respectively. [] []
[2023-01-11 21:10:53] main.WARNING: Broken reference: The element with the "sidebar.additional" ID wasn't found. Verify the ID and try again. [] []
```

The same can be found in system.log:

```
[2023-01-11 21:10:49] main.WARNING: Broken reference: The element with the "sidebar.additional" ID wasn't found. Verify the ID and try again. [] []
[2023-01-11 21:10:53] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-01-11 21:10:53] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-01-11 21:10:53] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-01-11 21:10:53] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sw.sidenav' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.main', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-01-11 21:10:53] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sidebar_second_block' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.second', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-01-11 21:10:53] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'product_view_custom_block' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-01-11 21:10:53] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'currency' tries to reorder itself towards 'store_language', but their parents are different: 'header.panel' and 'porto_header' respectively. [] []
[2023-01-11 21:10:53] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.link' tries to reorder itself towards 'top.links', but their parents are different: 'header.links' and 'header.panel' respectively. [] []
[2023-01-11 21:10:53] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'yotpo_bottomline' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.addto', but their parents are different: 'product.info.main' and 'product.info.social' respectively. [] []
[2023-01-11 21:10:53] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sw.sidenav' tries to reorder itself towards 'category_leftnav', but their parents are different: 'sidebar.main' and '' respectively. [] []
[2023-01-11 21:10:53] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sidebar_second_block' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'sidebar.second' and '' respectively. [] []
[2023-01-11 21:10:53] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'skip_gallery_before' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.media.image', but their parents are different: 'skip_gallery_before.wrapper' and 'product.info.media' respectively. [] []
[2023-01-11 21:10:53] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'skip_gallery_after' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.media.image', but their parents are different: 'skip_gallery_after.wrapper' and 'product.info.media' respectively. [] []
[2023-01-11 21:10:53] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'amasty.rewards.highlight.container' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.form.content', but their parents are different: 'alert.urls' and 'product.info' respectively. [] []
[2023-01-11 21:10:53] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'product_view_custom_block' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'sidebar.additional' and '' respectively. [] []
[2023-01-11 21:10:53] main.WARNING: Broken reference: The element with the "sidebar.additional" ID wasn't found. Verify the ID and try again. [] []
```

---

**UPDATE:
This is now not loading on the computer either!**

*Would anyone know how to fix this?*

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to disable the amasty module via running the command

   php bin/magento module:disalbe extension name
2. You can check the log files from magento root directory/var/log/

Comment: I updated my original post with some info from log files. Also, if I disable the Amasty module and it destroys the site completely, how would I re-enable it again? Thank you.

Comment: You have to run this command to enable the Amasty extension.
php bin/magento module:enable extension name